# Why does this change to SafeSubscriber for subsciption

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, rxjs

I need to find out why my `this` object changes from `view controller` to `SafeSubscriber` in my `TS` & `ionic` app.

My data service:

```
getStationData(name:string){

        let myURL = "http://some/url/request.php?name="+ name;

        return this.http.get(myURL)
                .map(
                    res => {return this.parseData(res._body);},
                    err => console.log(err));
};
```

My view controller:

```
//here, this is still the correct object : view controller
this._dataService.getStationData(name).subscribe((data) =>{
    //here, this now becomes of type safe subscriber?
    console.log(this);
    //when I hover in chrome over this, it shows all view controller parameters.
    //but when I call a method, it's not defined?
});
```

Is there something wrong with the `http.get` request?

Comment: You are passing an error handler to the [`map` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map) as the `thisArg`. That most likely has something to do with your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it. Interestingly it used to work with previous Angular / Ionic versions but after a more recent update fails now...